# model passed into dictionary is of type A but required of type B

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Posts.Models.RegisterViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Posts.Models.RegisterViewModelForm'

Okay so this is the error I get every time I try to register a user using my blogging website that I developed on C# using ASP.NET.

The most baffling part is that it was working just fine couple of months ago. My professor even tested this part in front of me and I passed with flying colors. I did developed this project on my old laptop , which didn't had Windows 8.1 and I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 right now.

I tried changing the parameter of the post method Register to RegisterViewModelForm but it didn't worked and I tried debugging it also.It executes fine until it reaches the submit button, and after that this error happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Model

```
 public class RegisterViewModelForm
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "First name(s)")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList RolesList { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
 //
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        //return View();

        var registerForm = new RegisterViewModelForm();

        registerForm.RolesList = new MultiSelectList(new List<string> { "Administrator", "Blogger", "Commenter" });
        //registerForm.RolesList = new MultiSelectList(new List<string> {"Blogger", "Commenter" });



        return View(registerForm);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { Email = model.Email,UserName = model.UserName, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                //await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("http://http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", "administrator"));

                //await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("http://http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", "blogger"));

                //await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("http://http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", "commenter"));

                await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, model.Email));
                await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, model.FirstName));
                await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, model.LastName));
                await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));

                // Add 'role' claims

                foreach (var role in model.Roles)
                {
                    await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                }

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);


                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Pictures");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

My view

```html
@model Posts.Models.RegisterViewModelForm
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Roles">Roles</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @{
    foreach (var item in Model.RolesList)
    {
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="Roles" value="@item.Text" />@item.Text
            </label>
        </div>
    }
            }
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Your view is based on `RegisterViewModelForm` but you post it back to a method which has parameter `RegisterViewModel`. But `ModelState` is invalid and you return the view but now pass it `RegisterViewModel` hence the error. Your POST method must be `RegisterViewModelForm` and if it is valid, initialize a new instance of `RegisterViewModel` map its properties from the model and save it.

Comment: And `ModelState` will always be invalid since `RegisterViewModel` contains a required property `UserName` which is not in the view so it will always be `null`. What is the point of using 2 models here (they are both view models). Also `MultiSelectList RolesList` makes no sense (a `MultiSelectList` is for use in `DropdownListFor()`) and you current usage means you can only select one role so the `foreach` loop in the POST method makes no sense.

Comment: The view does have a field UserName.

Comment: Just use one view model. There is no point in having 2 models for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please,

Check out your POST method  :  it should be a RegisterViewModelForm. If it doesn't work, clean and rebuild all.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModelForm model)
```

Comment: I think i got it : do you hit the controller post method ? if the ModelState is not valid, then it returns View(RegisterViewModel) but the view takes a Posts.Models.RegisterViewModelForm.

Comment: I think that is the problem also , but I don't know why that happens . I don't understand why and where my modelState is invalid.

Comment: ModelState is a dictionary of (property, error) you can check with the debugger